# Yii url case sensitivity

Tags: php, yii, yii-url-manager

In Yii I have controller named like this `SomethingSomethingElseController`
in windows everything is fine, but when I deploy on linux server I get

```
Unable to resolve the request "somethingsomethingelse/index"
```

and when change url path to `somethingSomethingElse/index` it works fine again
if I set caseSensitive to false in urlManager config I get Unable to resolve error no matter how I type controller id in url path

thanks

Comment: Simply type the controller name with proper capitalization when you are creating URLs. If you are creating URLs from named routes then you would only have to do this once (when specifying the routes).

Comment: Read Qiang's comments on the case-sensitive URL issue here http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/651-controller-file-name-case-sensitive/page__p__15145#entry15145

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue is at the operating system/partition level. You need to be sure to **always** use proper casing if you want your links to work on multiple machines. Unfortunately you will have to run your local system on a linux or other partition that is case-sensitive if you want to catch the bugs before you push it live.

It is always better to have your testing/local server as close to your production servers as possible.

Answer (score -1):

One option might be to use the section of the rules urlmager. Creating the rule 'controller / method' => 'controller / Method', but I do not think the best way, you found a solution to this problem, which I also was presenting me this